# Does algolia support custom domains?

Tags: algolia

We are adding search API in our product offering powered by Algolia. We will like our customers to use Algolia search REST API directly in their apps but we want the REST API url to carry our service name and not Algolia. Does Algolia support custom domains that just DNS forward the traffic to their API with no proxy required in between?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algolia doesn't support custom domains currently. The only way to achieve this would be with a proxy in-between as you mention.

Comment: But wont that actually increase the latency?

Any better solution?